# What is the `Join()` method on `List().Join()` used for?

Tags: c#, arrays

I came across this

```
List().Join()
```

And was wondering

*How can the `Join()` portion in the above line of code (on the right side of `List` be used ?*

This looks similar to the following :

```
String.Join()
```

...but it has a more complex IntelliSense tool-tip as displayed below :

[image: convoluted join()]

Comment: Why can't you just use `String.Join("", myList);`?  Why do you *have* to use something like `myList.Join("");`?

Comment: FWIW the intellisense you see is for the Linq `Join` extension method for combining two collections, which is _very_ different than `string.Join`.

Comment: @rory.ap if you notice I addressed that I am aware of how to do this the other way --  I would like to know how to use the extension in place as it is available off the enumerator.

Comment: @DStanley Thank you .  That actually cleared up why that was there (voted up)  I commented out the reference to LINQ, and the extension vanished.

Comment: I am not sure why the downvotes as there really wasn't anything I could 'google' per say that showed this was part of linq without having first known it was part of linq.  At a glance, it looks like a convoluted regular join method due to accepting `byte[]` as it's first parameter, and I was genuinely curious as to how to use this since it is there.  Not that I *must* use it, just to know for the sake of knowing.

Comment: @DStanley since you have provided the correct solution, I updated the closest solution by Sevvy to include that information (as well as my question above) since it seemed people were reading too much into it thinking I was implying something or wanted a work-around instead of just information about that specific use.  For the community, it is still open to add (or modify a solution) an example on the use as the syntax is in the tooltip since MSDN shows a completely different format.

Comment: FYI - I up-voted all solutions provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no instance or extension method in .NET for a sequence of strings that will join them together as `String.Join` does.  If you want such an extension method you'll have to write it yourself (which should be trivially easy, given that internally all it needs to do is call `string.Join`).

`Enumerable.Join`, which is the method you are seeing on `IEnumerable<T>`, is referring to a Join in the set context, like what SQL does, and is a very different kind of operation.

Comment: Is there no way to use that ?  Essentially I am looking for an example on how to use it based off the extension that is visible.

Comment: @SamuelJackson The `Enumerable.Join` method has nothing at all to do with this.   It's a conceptually entirely different operation.  If you want to concatenate a sequence of strings with a provided separator, `string.Join` is exactly the method to use, and it's not an extension on `IEnumerable<T>`, so if you want that, you need to create it yourself.  again, it's one very easy line of code to write, but you *do* have to write it.

Comment: D Stanley   cleared up where that superfluous `Join` command was coming from.  Makes more sense now.  If you wish to add that to your answer so it is more complete, I can accept this solution.   The other solutions work as extension method workarounds (and are useful for others who come here), but it was not what I was looking for.  I saw the Join extension and was curious if it could be used that way. Knowing it is LINQ, I immediately know how to use it if i so desire :)

Answer (score 2):

`Join` is a regular static method of the class `String`. The syntax you want to use can only be used with extension methods. If you really insist on being able to use it like that simply create your own:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> enumeration, string separator)
       => string.Join(separator, enumeration);
}
```

Comment: I was considering this, but this wasn't what I was looking for.  I was curious about that specific `.Join` command off the right side, and if it could be used.  I know now that is part of Linq, and thus inherently know how to use it (if i so desired).  Curiosity sated!  (up-voted tho)

Answer (score 1):

Do this, and now you have the syntax you want.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods 
{
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> stringarray, string separator) 
    {
        return String.Join(separator, stringarray);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was considering this, but this wasn't what I was looking for.  I was curious about that specific `.Join` command off the right side, and if it could be used.  I know now that is part of Linq, and thus inherently know how to use it (if i so desired).  Curiosity sated!  (up-voted tho)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `myList` is a **list** of strings. The Join function is a very string specific function. Since a list doesn't make any assumptions about what is inside the list (ei you can store integers, floats, user defined classes etc...) it doesn't make any sense for a list to include a function that is so specific to only string.

This is why lists don't have a `myList.Join` because anything could be in that list. You'll unfortunately have to stick with `String.Join()` as unelegant as it is.

Comment: I disagree with the implied `can't` (or reason there-of ), as older languages like *Visual Basic 6* were able to automatically cast int as string and back without any requirement to pre-cast.  Even still, something like this could work on a list of strings, so have the `.Join()` extension show up on that enumerator only (as was written in other solutions on this post.  Although they would arguably perform slightly faster if the method was native instead of a wrapper inside a hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IEnumerable.Aggregate like this

```
list.Aggregate((i, j) => i + j);
```

But string.join is the preffered method for performance.
Do not try to invent a custom syntax. You will lose readability by other C# devs. By the way it is possible with an extension method.

Comment: This isn't providing a separator, it breaks if there are no items in the sequence, and this will also perform *dramatically* worse, as it will end up creating n-1 intermediate strings, performing *lots* of completely unnecessary copies of the string data, wasting lots of CPU time and memory.  You lose a lot more than just readability here.

Comment: As I said, string.join is the preffered method and I was explicit about perfs... The readability part was a warning against worthless extension methods.

Comment: See my question modification for clarification in what I was looking for.  It was pretty much a 'tell me how to use this as it is shown, or what it is for' type question.  There really wasn't any reading into it for alternative solutions, although your suggestion is very creative :)  (and broken, but thinking outside the box !! )

Comment: @Guillaume So if you know that it's inferior in every possible way, why even propose it?  You run the risk of someone actually *using* it if you do that.

Comment: Because the question was also about linq extensions and it might be interesting to understand it to be able to use it in another context without strings.